# Restlet Invalid type signature for com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, restlet, objectify

Good day. I have been using restlet 2.1.1 for a while in this application in combination with objectify-appengine. Ever since a upgrade to the objectify side (3.1 to 4.0b) I have had issues with persisting any entities that contain a non-null GeoPt object where it has worked before.
Versions used:
 * appengine-java-1.7.4
 * Restlet-2.1.1
 * Objectify-appengine-4.0b

The error I get after starting up hosted mode seems like it may be a hint:

```
Invoking generator org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator
...
private com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt geoPt
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt
Verifying instantiability
Analyzing the fields of type 'com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt' that qualify for serialization
Field 'private final float latitude' will not be serialized because it is final
Field 'private final float longitude' will not be serialized because it is final
```

I can persist any entities as long as their GeoPt variable is null, as soon as I persist a non-null GeoPt in a data object I get the following error reported on appengine console:

```
12 Feb 2013 7:51:35 AM org.restlet.service.ConverterService toObject
WARNING: Unable to convert a [application/x-java-serialized-object+gwt,UTF-8] representation into an object of class
java.io.IOException: Couldn't read the GWT object representation: Invalid type signature for com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt
at org.restlet.ext.gwt.ObjectRepresentation.getObject(ObjectRepresentation.java:126)
at org.restlet.ext.gwt.GwtConverter.toObject(GwtConverter.java:149)
at org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toObject(ConverterService.java:167)
at org.restlet.resource.Resource.toObject(Resource.java:784)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:481)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:545)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.put(ServerResource.java:1234)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:425)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doNegotiatedHandle(ServerResource.java:646)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:341)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:942)
at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:246)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:431)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:648)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:154)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:211)
at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:84)
at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:377)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:431)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:648)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:431)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:648)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:211)
at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:392)
at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.restlet.engine.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:72)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:152)
at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1089)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Invalid type signature for com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.validateTypeVersions(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:1116)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:610)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:140)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:425)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:807)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:878)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:662)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:587)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:134)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:414)
at org.restlet.ext.gwt.ObjectRepresentation.getObject(ObjectRepresentation.java:122)
... 80 more
```

NB: Before someone suggests that I use DTOs or some other framework than Restlet or Objectify, I purposely chose this combination for a Restful service where it is possible to reuse Data Objects on the client side without cumbersome DTOs and conversions.

Thanks
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known bug: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/issues/detail?id=135

Comment: Thanks Thomas, since I was also using Restlet it looked like a possible issue there but alas I think youre right; I was hoping it was something I could fix without having to revert to 3.1 as that was marked Obsolete:-( I will revert and keep track of that specific issue